# How to build a completely static multipage website with BEM?

Tags: html, css, bem

All tutorials I've seen so far describe how to create single page sites or just several bundles. Here is an example of a simple website navigation:

- example.com/home
- example.com/about
- example.com/services

  - example.com/services/marketing
  - example.com/services/development
- example.com/contact

Is it possible to build such a site with bem-tools, bemjson, bemhtml but without any serverside tech like node.js or php?

The build should include only a directory with final .html, .css, .js files and images per page and should be hosted on a static file hosting like Amazon S3. It should also be an oldschool static website, not a single page ajax site.

Is there any easy to use solution for this use case or should one create her own build process to collect the files from the bundle directories?

Comment: This question is adressed in part [on ya.ru](http://clubs.ya.ru/bem/replies.xml?item_no=3945) (only in russian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, and the answer is - yes, you can :)

First of all, you need to clone `project-stub` repo and install dependencies:

```
git clone git@github.com:bem/project-stub.git
cd project-stub
npm i
./node_modules/.bin/bem make libs
```

Now you have configured project stub to develop site with bem-tools.

Page `index` is included.

Let's create page `about`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/bem create -b about -l desktop.bundles/
```

This command creates file `desktop.bundles/about/about.bemjson`, which represents your page in BEM terms.

[image: page about]

You can see this page when you run

```
./node_modules/.bin/bem server
```

and open `http://localhost:8080/desktop.bundles/about/about.html` in browser.

[image: about page]

Read more: http://bem.info/libs/bem-core/1.0.0/bemhtml/reference/, "The Input Data: BEMJSON" chapter.

To get final css with rigth image path's, you need to install `cssrb` package:

sudo npm i cssrb -g

And to get final build directory, you need to put [`bem-static-build.sh`](https://github.com/alexbaumgertner/bem-static-build) file in root of your project and run it:

```
 wget https://raw.github.com/alexbaumgertner/bem-static-build/master/bem-static-build.sh
 sh  bem-static-build.sh
```

After builder process ended, you can find static site in `desktop.bundles/merged/build` folder:

[image: build]

NB:
If you have content images on your page, you must put them into `desktop.bundles/merged/img` folder and make symlinks to all pages folders:

```
ln -s $(pwd)/desktop.bundles/merged/img $(pwd)/desktop.bundles/index/img
ln -s $(pwd)/desktop.bundles/merged/img $(pwd)/desktop.bundles/about/img
```

and etc for all pages. This actions are needed because `bem server` shows a page relative to its folder and with symlink you can write image `src` in about.bemjson and all pages like this:

```
    {
        block: 'user',
        content: [
            {
                elem: 'avatar',
                tag: 'img',
                attrs: {
                    src: 'img/dypsilon.png' // relative way
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

and it should work!

Any questions are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for this great and comprehensive answer. This is not the easy way I was hoping for, but I will still accept this answer. In my understanding, there is no easier way right now.

Comment: Now I search a way to build static pages without any additional script, just by bem-tools (bem make part). If I find working solution - I will write about it.